# $A \in \mathscr A$, $S \subset \Omega$, $S \notin \mathscr A$ and $A \cap S \neq \emptyset$ $\Rightarrow$ $A \setminus S \in \mathscr A$?

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Assume $\Omega$ is a set and $\mathscr A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$. Now, let $A \in \mathscr A$, $S \subset \Omega$, $S \notin \mathscr A$ and $A \cap S \neq \emptyset$. I visualized this here:

[image]

What I wondered myself: Can we conclude that $A \setminus S \in \mathscr A$? The picture seems to say Yes, but I don't know how I could give a good argument for it. Could we possibly simply assume that the part of $S$ that lies in $\mathscr A$ is necessarily some $B \in \mathscr A$, and hence, $A \setminus S = A \setminus B \in \mathscr A$? If so, why?

Comment: No. If $|X| \geq 2$ and $\mathcal{A} = \{\emptyset, X\}$, then this is automatically false.